# Recyclerview with rows and columns?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is it possible to have `RecyclerView` look like a grid? I.e. look like a 3x3 matrix?

The orientation can be only `HORIZONTAL` or `VERTICAL`. In iOS I can have `UICollectionView` have sections and rows. What about `RecyclerView` in Android?

Comment: Did you even try to google that? Use `GridLayoutManager`: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html

Comment: @Than funny it says `RecyclerView` is modernized version of the `ListView` and the `GridView`, but how to make a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: Use `GridLayoutManager`!

Comment: YOu can use GridLayoutManager and inside adapter getItemCount method return value 3

Comment: If you really need a fixed 3x3 matrix then RecyclerView is overkill, GridView is enough.

Comment: @Enzokie but `GridView` is as efficient as `RecyclerView` when reusing cells?

Comment: @János RecyclerView is a big-big win when the datasets are dynamic because it uses a special data structure that reuse the ViewHolder (often called as pool) on the other hand it is overkill if you just need a small and fixed number of cells. But you do not need to overthink my statement since it has only a little impact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes that is possible. You just need to replace your `LinearLayoutManager` with `GridLayoutManager`.
Before setting the adapter you need to set following lines

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), int_value(of no of items to be in one row);
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

It will show int_value no of elements in one row.For a square grid(3x3), you will have to give 9 items to the adapter.

Comment: And what if you want the num of items to be the max that fits in the row?